# unable to create use cloudinary in RestFulWeb service java project

Tags: java, cloudinary

```
 Map config = new HashMap();
            config.put("cloud_name", cloudName);
            config.put("api_key", apiKey);
            config.put("api_secret", apiSecret);
            System.out.print("cloudName:"+cloudName +"   apiKey:"+apiKey+"   apiSecret:"+apiSecret);
            Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);
```

> java.lang.UnknownError: Can't find Cloudinary platform adapter
>   [com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http42.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http43.UploaderStrategy]

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.UnknownError: Can't find Cloudinary platform adapter [com.cloudinary.android.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http42.UploaderStrategy,com.cloudinary.http43.UploaderStrategy]  this is  the complete error..

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies changed a little bit with the new Java library version.
If you're building a JAVA app, you can use something like:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudinary-http44</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2</version>
</dependency>
```

For Android:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.cloudinary</groupId>
    <artifactId>cloudinary-android</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```